# How to cast an object into type of another variable in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on an entity framework project and I'm trying to form a generic structure for adding joins to my table.

```
class BrowseCONTACTS_BASE : MyBrowseFrm<CONTACTS_BASE>
{
  public BrowseCONTACTS_BASE()
    {
        MyInitialize();
    }
    public void MyInitialize()
    {
        //Here I may have more joins
        MyAddJoins<ORDERS>("CONTACTS_BASE", "CB_REFNO", "ORDERS", "OR_REFNO", "OR_REFNO");
    }
}
```

On the parent class **MyBrowseFrm**

```
 partial class MyBrowseFrm<TEntity>:Form where TEntity:class
 {
 }
```

I have the following:

MyAddJoins Function that I call from the child class above

```
protected void MyAddJoins<TTable>(string pParent, string pParentKey, string pChild, string pChildKey,
        string pDisplayField) where TTable:class, new()
    {            
       var a = new TTable();

        var item = new MyJoins<dynamic>
        {
            Parent = pParent,
            Child = pChild,
            ParentKey = pParentKey,
            ChildKey = pChildKey,
            DisplayField = pDisplayField,
            ChildTable = a
        };

        MyBdJoins.Add(item);
    }

//A list to store Joins added from the child table
private List<MyJoins<dynamic>> MyBdJoins;

protected struct MyJoins<TTable> where TTable : class
    {
        public string Parent;
        public string ParentKey;
        public string Child;
        public string ChildKey;
        public string DisplayField;
        public TTable ChildTable;
    }
```

Ok this is the part where I'm stuck, The following code will run when I press the search button.

```
private void MyGenerateQuery()
    {   
        //Here I cast my Context to CONTACTS_BASE
        var loContext = (DbSet<TEntity>)Context.GetPropValue(boName);            

        foreach (var join in MyBdJoins)
        {              
            loContext
                .Join(
                    (DbSet<ORDERS>)Context.GetPropValue(join.Child),
                    par => par.GetPropValue(join.ParentKey),
                    chld => chld.GetPropValue(join.ChildKey),
                    (par, chld) => new { GetPropValue = chld.GetPropValue(join.DisplayField) }
                );
        }

        myGridView1.DataSource = loContext.ToList();
    }
```

The code above at the part where it is:

```
(DbSet<ORDERS>)Context.GetPropValue(join.Child)
```

Here what I want to do is:

```
(DbSet<TTable>)Context.GetPropValue(join.Child)
```

of course, the above code gives me an error.

Note: in my code `TEntity` is CONTACTS_BASE and `TTable` is ORDERS

so how do I cast this object to type `TTable`
where it is in MyJoins Structure

```
public TTable ChildTable;
```

**EDIT:**

```
 public partial class ORDERS
{
    public int OR_REFNO { get; set; }
    public string OR_PROD_CODE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> OR_DATE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OR_M_REFNO { get; set; }

    public virtual CONTACTS_BASE CONTACTS_BASE { get; set; }
    public virtual ORDER_TYPES ORDER_TYPES { get; set; }
}



public partial class CONTACTS_BASE
{
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public CONTACTS_BASE()
    {
        this.ORDERS = new List<ORDERS>();
    }

    public int CB_REFNO { get; set; }
    public string CB_NAME { get; set; }
    public string CB_ID_NO { get; set; }
    public string CB_AGE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CB_TEL_NO { get; set; }
    public string CB_EMAIL { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> CB_ENROLL_DATE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> CB_START_DATE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> CB_END_DATE { get; set; }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual IList<ORDERS> ORDERS { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Automapper or implicit cast or LINQ's Select over list with explicit cast

Comment: Hi Samvel, can u provide me an example or something to read, please? I'm completely lost here...

Comment: As an aside, you have misspelled `MyBrowseForm` in your code. Please don't just randomly abbreviate words in names; you simply make your code harder to read.

Comment: Can you please add the source code of the `CONTACTS_BASE` and `ORDERS`

Comment: Samvel, I have added the class implementations, they are auto generated from my database by entity framework